# How to treat the last term in equation $X(t) = \int_0^t ds \hspace{0.1 cm} a(s)X(s) + \int_0^t K(t, s) dW(s) + \frac{d W(t)}{dt}$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I would like to solve an stochastic equation $X(t) = \int_0^t ds \hspace{0.1 cm} a(s)X(s) + \int_0^t K(t, s) dW(s) + \frac{d W(t)}{dt}$ numerically.

where:
$X(t)$ is the dependent variable, which evolves over time;

$a(t)$ is a deterministic function that describes how $X(t)$ changes with time.

$W(t)$ describes a Brownian motion.

Could someone explain me how the treat the term $\frac{d W(t)}{dt}$ ?

Comment: In what context did you see this? Clasically, $\frac{dW}{dt}$ means nothing, as $W$ is of nowhere differentiable.

Comment: @JoseAvilez In a condensed matter problem, in which I try to find a non-markovian Langevin-like equation from the Keldish formalism. So, does the general approach neglect the dW(t)/dt term?

I considered trying to dW(t)/dt = $\sigma$ W(t), where $\sigma$ should be a constant. Does this make sense?

Comment: no, your proposed approach doesn't make sense. What one might do is treat this "derivative" as gaussian white noise. Also, in your original equation you have $X_t$ on both sides; is that as intended?

Comment: @JoseAvilez Thanks for the answer. It is more complicated. I present a simplified version(meanwhile, I update the question). Since this topic is new to me,  could you explain how I numerically treat the "derivative" as Gaussian white noise? Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: Apart from the problems mentioned in the earlier comments, what is $\int_0^t ds K(t, s) dW(t)$ ? From where to where do you integrated $ds$ and same question about $dW(t)$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. Sorry, I made a mistake, I haven't noticed. Thanks for the comment.